# IIS6 is not finding .asp files

Tags: windows, asp-classic, iis-6

Hoping someone can provide an answer with this, although it's not 100% programming related.  All of a sudden my IIS6 install on Server 2003 will give me a "404 Not Found" error when I try to load any file ending in .asp.

I can see the file there if I turn on directory browsing, but clicking on it immediately gives me a 404.  Regular HTML pages load just fine, it's only the ASP files that it cannot find, although they're right in the directory alongside the HTML file.

I'm probably forgetting something stupid - can someone remind me what I need to do in order to get it to load properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Web Service Extensions area, make sure Active Server Pages is enabled

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue of late. Besides the Web service extensions where one enables asp, there is another place in each site that needs to be checked.

**Virtual directory:**
In IIS 6.0, open the properties of the virtual directory. Navigate to virtual directory tab - at the bottom, click on configuration - make sure that the .asp extension is in that list. If it's not, you can find the dll somewhere like this path:  *C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll*. Also, the verbs will need to be added on this same window. The main choices are GET, HEAD, POST (and maybe TRACE if need be).

**Web site**
In IIS 6.0, open the properties of the site. Navigate to Home DIrectory tab - at the bottom, click on configuration - make sure that the .asp extension is in that list. If it's not, you can find the dll somewhere like this path:  *C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll.* Also, the verbs will need to be added on this same window. The main choices are GET, HEAD, POST (and maybe TRACE if need be).

I hope that helps - I didn't find this mentioned after a fairly extensive search.

Answer (score 0):

Duh - I knew it was something stupid that I just overlooked (shows how often I use Classic ASP).  Thanks a bunch.